# File Too Large Error Handling Nodejs Express Multer

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I am using multer with ExpressJS. I want to limit file uploads to 0.5 MB.

```
var limits = { fileSize: 0.5 * 1024 * 1024 };

var upload = multer({ dest: './public/uploads/', limits: limits
 }).single('upl')

 app.post('/',upload, function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
            console.log("cs " + err);
      return
    }

           res.end('You new avatar is uploaded')
    // Everything went fine
  })
})
```

When the file is under 0.5 MB I can see 'You new avatar is uploaded' but when it is over I get,

```
Error: File too large
   at makeError (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\nodejs projects\dummy\node_modules\multer\lib\make-error.js:12:13)
   at abortWithCode (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\nodejs projects\dummy\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:77:22)
   at FileStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\nodejs projects\dummy\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:139:11)
   at emitNone (events.js:80:13)
   at FileStream.emit (events.js:179:7)
   at PartStream.onData (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\nodejs projects\dummy\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:220:18)
   at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
   at PartStream.emit (events.js:182:7)
   at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
   at PartStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
```

Obviously I would never want the end user to see this. How can I handle this properly?

Comment: That error is being returned to the browser? I'm surprised.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try rewrite like this (remove "upload" first):

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("cs " + err);
      return
    }

    res.end('You new avatar is uploaded')
    // Everything went fine
  })
```

Comment: But then how will I introduce the size limit?

Comment: write like your code just remove upload middleware in app.post('/')

Answer (score 1):

I've created an Express handler in the end of `server.js` file.

1. place handler function after all `app.use()`, check if this error from multer and send data you needed.
   My code sends `LIMIT_FILE_SIZE` string.

```
app.use(() => (err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        return res.status(418).send(err.code);
    }
});
```

Docs: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#error-handling