# MulterError: File too large using Node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-storage, multer

I have no restrictions on my file size set in my Multer constructor, but I am getting the error

```
MulterError: File too large
    at abortWithCode (/Users/kelseygbates/demo3/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:79:22)
    at FileStream.<anonymous> (/Users/kelseygbates/demo3/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:141:11)
    at FileStream.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at PartStream.onData (/Users/kelseygbates/demo3/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:220:18)
    at PartStream.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:276:11)
    at PartStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:231:10)
    at Dicer._oninfo (/Users/kelseygbates/demo3/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:191:36)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (/Users/kelseygbates/demo3/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:127:10)
```

When I try to upload a .mov file of size 14.9 MB. I have multer connected directly to a Google Cloud Storage bucket, which is where I want to store this file. Based on the Multer documentation, the default file size limit is infinity, so I am not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289130/file-too-large-error-handling-nodejs-express-multer

Comment: Could you show us the relevant piece of code too?

Comment: Take a look at the below link i think this will help you a little to setup multer with gc( google cloud ) Link : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-cloud-storage